# rbenv version 2.2.1 is not installed, even though it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm having an issue where I've run the following commands in my local project

```
rbenv install 2.2.1
rbenv local 2.2.1
rbenv rehash
```

But then the second I try to run any ruby command (i.e. `gem`, `ruby`, `bundle`, etc), I get the error message:

```
rbenv: version `2.2.1' is not installed (set by /path/to/my/folder/.ruby-version)
```

I'm at a loss for why this is happening. I've deleted and re-cloned the repository and I've tried running `rbenv global 2.2.1`.

Rbenv is installing my ruby versions to `/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/` if that's helpful at all.

Also, I have `/Users/congel/.rbenv/bin:/Users/congel/.rbenv/shims:` prepended to my `$PATH`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: what does `ruby -v` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that a long time ago I must have needed to change my `RBENV_ROOT` variable.

I had a line in my .bash_profile that was essentially changing the installation folder for rbenv's ruby versions.

Took the line out and everything works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a `.ruby-version` file defining a specific version number at root of project. I was in a project sub-folder, nothing there. Also checked my home dir, nothing there either.

Never thought looking at project root, but found out about it by running `rbenv version` command:

```
jmiettunen@MAC ThirdParty (master) $ rbenv version
rbenv: version `2.2.2' is not installed
 (set by /Users/jmiettunen/git/myProject/.ruby-version)
```